# accessing json data ( array of strings) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My json text is of the form ["string1" , "string2", ...].

How do I convert this to a javascript array and display the values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: but there are no key:value pairs here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSON library https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js

```
var array =  JSON.parse('["string1" , "string2", "string3"]');
```

Or using jQuery

```
var array =  $.parseJSON('["string1" , "string2", "string3"]');
```

Or using `eval` ( Not recommended )

```
var array =  eval('["string1" , "string2", "string3"]');
```

Then array[0] , array[1] ...

Answer (score 0):

This is an array, if you open your developer console and try:

```
["string1" , "string2"][0]
--> "string1"

["string1" , "string2"].length
--> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create array
var myArrayFromJson =  JSON.parse('["string1" , "string2", "string3"]');

// iterate
for (var i=0;i<myArrayFromJson.length;(i=i+1)){
  console.log(myArrayFromJson[i]);
  // ... do things with myArrayFromJson[i] ...  
}
```